# Excel cubevalue with multiple cubesets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mdx, olap, cube

I am trying to get a cubevalue from 4 things: 2 cubemembers and 2 cubesets.

I have something like:

```
CUBEVALUE("connection";cubemember1;cubemember2;cubeset1;cubeset2)
```

The thing is that both "cubeset1" and "cubeset2" more than 1 object.
All these members work fine separately, but the expression gives me the #VALUE! error.

Also, when I convert the original OLAP cube to formulas, which displayed values as an OLAP cube, these same values appear as an error #VALUE!.

Already checked the recommended solution of making sure the set_expressions are not bigger than 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If they work separately ok then why not use the following in a cell:

```
CUBEVALUE("connection";cubemember1;cubeset1) 
+
CUBEVALUE("connection";cubemember2;cubeset2)
```